# Is overriding of constraints() and removeConstraints() necessary when creating a custom control?

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, uicontrol

I'm creating a custom control that uses auto-layout to arrange its subviews.

Naturally, I don't want users of my custom control to inadvertently mess with these internal constraints when programmatically manipulating the control's constraints so I thought I should override `constraints()` to hide those internal ones the user should never need to know about and also `removeConstraints()` to prevent the user from removing them.

But then it occurred to me that `UIKit` itself probably invokes `constraints()` and/or `removeConstraints()` and expects to be able to see all of them.

So, should I or should I not, override `constraints()` and `removeConstraints()` ?

Comment: @luk2302 Is there any particular reason why you felt necessary to delete 'Thanks in advance for any answers and comments.' from my post?

Comment: It is noise and does not contribute to the solution or the actual question. It is pretty self-explanatory that you are thankful for any help. Do not take it as an offense, I remove them whenever I see them. Take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts for a dicussion about that topic.

Comment: From the looks of it, there are about as many people who think an edit like that is necessary as there are who think it's not. I am _strongly_ in the camp that being polite is a necessary part of being in any community. My post above was very carefully written to be clear, concise, precise, and typo-free. There was no reason whatsoever to edit it other than your personal view that a 'thank you' at the end (at the very end, separated from the rest of the post, no less) was uncalled for.

Comment: It is not only my personal view, no! The top 3 answers to the linked questions state that greetings and salutations could / should be removed. If you think this is wrong, request moderator attention or just leave it as it is.

Comment: I disagree with your edit (and the general policy if that's the general policy) but I won't make a big deal about it by dragging this discussion any further.

Comment: If you do disagree then head over to meta and start a discussion there, that is exactly the kind of dicussion that site was made for.

Comment: @wltrup Before you file a bug on CGColorGetComponents, email me and I'll explain it to you. Or undelete that question so I can write the answer. :)

Comment: @matt Thank you, Matt, but I've already filed a radar. I'll contact you off SO shortly.

Comment: @wltrup Then close your radar. :) There's nothing wrong here. - I'd prefer you just undeleted the question so I can earn the glory of the checkmark.